# How do you get the username of a Windows Azure Mobile Services user?

Tags: ios, identity, azure-mobile-services

Once a user has authenticated, how do I get the username of their account?  I couldn't see anything in MSUser.h that would help.  Do I have to do it differently for each of the 4 different identity providers?

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean on the client or server side? In server code, you can use `getIdentities()` on the `user` object that is always a parameter in the server scripts. The properties are different for each of the providers, as follows:

```
{ 
    "facebook":{ 
        "userId":"Facebook:my-actual-user-id", 
        "accessToken":"the-actual-access-token" 
    } 
}
```

And for Twitter:

```
{ 
    "twitter":{ 
        "userId":"Twitter:my-actual-user-id", 
        "accessToken":"the-actual-access-token", 
        "accessTokenSecret":"the-actual-access-token-secret" 
    } 
}
```

Microsoft:

```
{ 
    "microsoft":{ 
        "userId":"MicrosoftAccount:my-actual-user-id", 
        "accessToken":"the-actual-access-token" 
    } 
}
```

Google:

```
{ 
    "google":{ 
        "userId":"Google:my-actual-user-id", 
        "accessToken":"the-actual-access-token" 
    } 
}
```

([Taken from **Carlos Figueira**'s excellent blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx) which goes into more detail)

On the client side, I haven't used the iOS SDK, but in JavaScript it is `client.currentUser.userId`

Comment: Using the latest version and there doesn't seem to be a way to get the access tokens anymore (even with the Users preview feature enabled), a call to getIdentities only return the provider object with the userId. I've also complained that the documentation is incorrect regarding this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj554220.aspx.
Without access tokens, you can't even make the majority of API calls to the provider to get additional user information.